# Cycles in $x^n + \dfrac1{x^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Fix $x \in \mathbb R$ (or $ \mathbb C$) with $x\ne0$ and let $a_n=x^n + \dfrac1{x^n}$.

It's a nice exercise to prove, *without computing $x$*, that the sequence $(a_n)$ is periodic when $a_1=1$.

Are there other values of $a_1$ for which $(a_n)$ is periodic?

What can be said in general about this sequence?

Since $x$ and $\dfrac1x$ are the roots of $t^2-a_1 t+1$, it follows from Newton's identities that $$a_{n+2}=a_1 a_{n+1} - a_n$$
Perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be periodic a sequence must be bounded.
It follows that your sequence may be periodic only if $x\in S^1$, i.e. $x=e^{i\theta}$.
In such a case
$$ a_n = 2\cos(n\theta) $$
is periodic iff $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Of course! Excellent!